# How to refresh directory using dos command?

Tags: windows, maven, batch-file

I have created a batch file of dos commands as below,

```
mvn compile war:war

move C:\Users\xyz\demo1\target\*.war C:\Users
```

First command is for generate a war file

Second command is for moving that war file to another directory

My first command works fine and generates a war file but my second command is not able to move that file.

While I execute second command separately, it works fine

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: What message do you get? Did you try without the wildcard?

Comment: Why do you have 2 backslashes before *.war?

Comment: sorry matt, 2 backslashes are by mistake. Actually it's only one.

Answer (score 1):

Is mvn command a Batch file `mvn.bat`? If so, you must execute it via `call` command:

```
call mvn compile war:war

move C:\Users\xyz\demo1\target\*.war C:\Users
```

Answer (score 0):

Test with a timeout just to check if your `mvn` not give the hand quicker as it create the `.war` file:

```
mvn compile war:war
PING localhost -n 3 -w 1000
move C:\Users\xyz\demo1\target\*.war C:\Users
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this and watch for error messages on the console window.

```
mvn compile war:war
move "C:\Users\xyz\demo1\target\*.war" "C:\Users"
pause
```